# Build a Js\Ts package under 'self-defined Debug\Release mode'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i'm a beginner in JavaScript\TypeScript. i wanna add some debug codes & functions in my .js.ts files by using such method below:

```
var de = false; // true when debugging
function bug( msg ){ ... display msg ... }
de&&bug( "hello world");
```

When using this method, i set 'true' and build package, will the package be bigger than 'false'??   In other words, the complier or the builder will ignore the 'condtion1' when 'condition0' && 'condition1' and the 'condition0' is false?

Hope i am clear! Thanks a lot! Good luck!

Comment: There are lots of build optimizers. UglifyJS is a very popular one that you might look into. That said, as you are new to JavaScript, I recommend that you become familiar with the fundamentals of the language before concerning yourself with such optimizations.

Comment: i used to code with c\c++，but now i got some tasks about web，so i'm not really familiar with js.